# Calling method from different UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, view

I am attempting to clear the `UIBezierPath` from a `UIView`. I have a class called `LinearSig` that has all the drawing functionality. (From a tutorial that I followed) I have the following method inside `LinearSig`:

```
- (void)clearSig {
    NSLog(@"clear");
    path = nil;  
    incrementalImage = nil;
    path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath]; 
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

When I call the method from my `SigViewController` the `NSLog` statements gets called and prints to the console, but the path does not get cleared. If I call the method from within the `LinearSig`, lets say after the touches method, the method works perfect. Everything gets erased.

I am calling the method from a different view controller because its all inside a custom `UIAlertView`.

this is how I'm calling the method

```
- (IBAction)clearSig:(id)sender {
    self.ls = [[LinearSig alloc] init];
    [self.ls clearSig];
}
```

`ls` is a property i have declared. any idea why this is not working?

Comment: You need to look into the difference between and instance and a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of `LinearSig` then clearing that. You need to point to the instance of `LinearSig` that you're trying to clear the graph off of.

Comment: Now that you say that it makes sense. Don't know what I was thinking. I was creating a new instance. I must have been brain fried.

Comment: It happens to the best of us!